# how to customize android material color palette

Tags: android, material-design

Actually i am working on one android app which contains material design navigation drawer,i want to change the colors of status bar,action bar,text color dynamically for every 5 min.Actually i am using supporting library theme to support all android mobiles.So main thing is i want to customize color palette.Please help me to resolve this.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name=”colorAccent”>@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're suggesting is possible using the method you're suggesting. Styles/themes/xml is static and can not be changed. To accomplish setting it dynamically, you'll have to get a reference to the widgets you want to change the background of and call the method to set the background of those items. For example:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(int);
```

Then you would just have to call this for every widget that you wanted to change the background of and on the root layout for your navigation drawer.